# How to get the background buffer of the WinForm control which is drawing by OpenGL via handle?

Tags: winforms, opengl

I draw the OpenGL window. I obtain the device context via GetDC ( hwnd). hwnd is C# winform handle (all works). How can I grab a background buffer of the Form? I tried this code (i call it on press button):

```
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bm;
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rec = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(10, 10, 1100, 1100);

        System.Drawing.Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();
        gr.Clip = new Region(rec);
        gr.Clear(Color.Yellow);

        bm = new Bitmap(rec.Width, rec.Height, gr);
        bm.Save("C:\\222.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

But it save the black square. How it can be solved? 
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Render to the form using opengl or save an image?

Comment: OpenGL draws in unmaneged C++. I transfer to C++ winform control handle to set device context for OpenGL outupt. I see the OpenGL output in my winform panel, but I want to get a screenshot via C#.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, only OpenGL commands can get the results of OpenGL rendering to a window. You can't do it with Win32 device context functions.